# Crystal Report Issue After deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

Got crystal report error specifically:

```
Failed to open the connection.
Details:  [Database Vendor Code: 17 ]Failed to open the connection.
ReportToday 4504_4604_{2CD4AF70-4D4E-4C5C-90F8-B60287F9454B}.rpt
Details:  [Database Vendor Code: 17 ]
```

In our web app we have 8 reports running smoothly in localhost. After deploying it in web, half of the reports are not working showing the error above. anyone has the idea how to fix this?

**Report Controller**

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Views/Reports/SalesMonthlyReport.rpt")));
rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "pass");
```

Comment: If the DB vendor is SQL Server, error 17 indicates the DB either does not exist, credentials mismatch or access denied. Try storing all DB required credentials for CR reports in web.config file (check if it uses invalid server name).

Comment: what do you mean by storing the credentials in web config?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto can you provide a snippet or idea of how i am going to do this. thanks

Comment: You can use `<appSettings>` section in web.config to set report & DB credentials like `ServerName`, `DatabaseName`, `ReportName`, `ReportPath`, `DBUser` & `DBPassword`. Ensure both `ServerName` and `DatabaseName` have correct names. Can you show where all report settings located?

Comment: A little tip: Find a part of your C# code which contains `ReportDocument` with calls of `SetConnection` method, since often the problem originated from connection settings.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto basically, all of 8 reports have that database connection settings, half of the total of the reports ran and half are not.

Comment: I suspected the line `rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "pass");` which used invalid host name at certain reports. Since I can't sure where the error thrown by current explanation, verify report connection-related codes together with web.config and controller part (include all necessary info to give many details).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto i tried storing db credentials including the server and the database name in appsettings then used it in one of the four reports that doesn't worked previously. Still not successful to work.